# CSS mask-image overlaps scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, fading, css-mask

I am working on a global fading behavior. General content that is located in a scrollable area (whether text or other content). Since the background of the individual areas is not always the same, I was looking for a solution that simply lets the content run transparently on scrolling. So you don't have to create a new fading for every piece of content.

Then I got the idea to do it with a mask that sets a gradient above and below.

Unfortunately I now have the problem that the mask is also above the scrollbar given by the browser.

Here a little example:

https://jsfiddle.net/2psemtzd/1/

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}

.scrollarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 0, #000 42px),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0, #000 42px);
  -webkit-mask-composite: source-in;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="scrollarea">
      <div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
        rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing
        elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna
        aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
        dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus
        est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in
        hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore
        eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio
        dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore
        te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
        adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet
        dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
        nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex
        ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in
        vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
        nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui
        blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait
        nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue
        nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy
        nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut
        wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper
        suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem
        vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie
        consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. At vero eos et
        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
        sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam
        diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et
        invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum.
        sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
        Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
        sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
        rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in
        vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
        nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui
        blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait
        nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
        elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
        aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
        tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
        velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla
        facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit
        praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla
        facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil
        imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
        euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi
        enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
        lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum
        iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,
        vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. At vero eos et accusam et
        justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam
        diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et
        invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum.
        sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
        Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
        sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,
        sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
        rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in
        vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat
        nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui
        blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait
        nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
        elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
        aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci
        tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate
        velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla
        facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit
        praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla
        facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil
        imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum
        dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh
        euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi
        enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit
        lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum
        iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,
        vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. At vero eos et accusam et
        justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
        takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam
        diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et
        invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum.
        sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
        nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.
        Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
        labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et
        accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no
        sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor
        sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
        gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy
        eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
        clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
        amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
        vero
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to exclude the scrollbar out of the mask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the mask differently considering the srollbar width. Not a perfect solution since the width of the scroll bar can be different for each browser but you can approximate the max value and use padding on the right:

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;  
}

.scrollarea {
  width: 80%;
  height: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  padding-right:5px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-mask:  /* 22px is the scroll width */
    linear-gradient(to top,   transparent, #000 ) 0 0    /calc(100% - 22px) 42px, 
    linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent, #000 ) 0 100% /calc(100% - 22px) 42px,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: destination-out;
  mask-composite:exclude;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="scrollarea">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   

Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   

Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.   

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.   

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.   

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.   

At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, At accusam aliquyam diam diam dolore dolores duo eirmod eos erat, et nonumy sed tempor et et invidunt justo labore Stet clita ea et gubergren, kasd magna no rebum. sanctus sea sed takimata ut vero voluptua. est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat.   

Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus.   

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi @Temani. Thanks for your help! At some cases it worked perfectly. But some contents are completely  transparent, so i cant see any content. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: @Adrian can you share the code doing this: https://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: Sorry i cant post the original code, cause its confidentiality.  

It feels like with -webkit-mask-composite: xor; its working good. What is the difference between destination-out and xor?